# recyclerview notifyDataSetChanged() is not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to update myadapter using notifyDataSetchanged() in updateList().But not working for recyclerview. I can able to see list size in updateList() and its displaying actual result but only reclerview is not updating.This class was designed in MVVM Design Pattern.

```
   public class TasksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TasksAdapter.TasksAdapterViewHolder> {
        private static final String TAG =  TasksAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        static ArrayList<ItemModel> list;
        static Context mContext;
        private Fragment fragment;
        private int row_index = -1;
        private SessionManager session;
    //    SelectColorVM colorVM;

        public TasksAdapter(Fragment fragment, Context context, ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.list = itemList;
            this.fragment = fragment;
            session = new SessionManager(fragment.getContext());
        }

        public void updateList(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList){
            list.clear();
            this.list = itemList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public TasksAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TasksItemBinding binding =
                    DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.tasks_item,
                            parent, false);
            return new TasksAdapter.TasksAdapterViewHolder(binding);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(TasksAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.binding.setViewModel(list.get(position));
            if(position == 0 && list.get(position).btnText.get().toString().length() > 0)
                holder.binding.btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                holder.binding.btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.binding.layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    //                row_index = position;
    //                notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    ItemModel item = list.get(position);
                    bundle.putSerializable("item", item);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_frame, fragment, "details");
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("details");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
            holder.binding.btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
                    if(list.get(position).btnText.get().equals("Task Start")){
                        LandingEngine.updateStatusAndSetStartTimeForRequest(fragment, user.get(SessionManager.KEY_CLEANER_ID), list.get(position).sid.get().toString());
                    } else if(list.get(position).btnText.get().equals("Task Complete")){
                        LandingEngine.updateStatusAndSetCompleteTimeForRequest(fragment, user.get(SessionManager.KEY_CLEANER_ID), list.get(position).sid.get().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public static class TasksAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TasksItemBinding binding;

            public TasksAdapterViewHolder(TasksItemBinding rowbinding) {
                super(rowbinding.getRoot());
                this.binding = rowbinding;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }


    }
```

I am calling adapter from my fragment like below

```
if(list.size() > 0) {
            if(adapter == null) {
                view.setHasFixedSize(true);
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragment.getContext());
                view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                adapter = new TasksAdapter(fragment, fragment.getContext(), list);
                view.setAdapter(adapter);
                view.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(fragment.getContext()));
            } else {
                adapter.updateList(list);
//                view.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
//                view.invalidate();
            }
        }
```

Please check this and let me know where i am doing wrong here.Thanks in advance..

Comment: why **`list.clear();`** in  **`updateList(list);`**

Comment: Its just for deleting previous data assigned in the list.

Comment: Remove this line  view.setHasFixedSize(true); otherwise make it false.

Comment: thanks for the reply @mehul but no luck

Comment: @malli solved this yet?

Comment: yes solved this problem by calling updatelist(list)  from fragment..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally its working by calling this method from fragment class once getting API response from the volley library.

I have written following method in ViewModel class.

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Class> list){
        if(adapter != null) {
            adapter.updateList(list);
        }
    }
```

And calling this method from fragment class like following.

```
ArrayList<StatisticsModel> list = (ArrayList) data;
        viewModel.updateList(list);
```

So in the adapter class update method is following.

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<StatisticsModel> itemList){
        list.clear();
//        this.list = itemList;
//        list.addAll(itemList);
//        notifyItemInserted(list.size());
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.list.addAll(itemList);
//        notifyItemInserted(list.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
 public void updateList(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList)
        {
            list.clear();
            this.list = itemList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

- Whenever calling this method **`list.clear();`** clear all value.

> The clear() method is used to remove all of the elements from a list.

**DO**

```
 public void updateList(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList)
            {
               this.list.addAll(itemList);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: @malli  `this.list .addAll(itemList);`

Comment: @malli for test case remove `if(adapter == null) {` condition and set `getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @malli i guess your IF block creating problem

Comment: it comes to else statement and can able to debug in adapter class updateList() but list is not refreshing its showing empty

Comment: When i comment that method working fine everytime adapter initializes and working like as expected, but i dont want to do it everytime, i am continuously updating

Comment: @malli call this onResume() section

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya   without creating new class for get and set how to update the recycler view  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661586/android-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-cant-updated-my-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem, you are doing mistake in this, change list into itemList:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                       view.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this remove **`list.clear();`** from your **`updateList`** method

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList){

            this.list.addAll(itemList);
            notifyItemInserted(list.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

> `notifyItemInserted(int position)`
>
> Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at position has been newly inserted.

also try this

```
        list.addAll(your new list);

        if (adapter == null) {
            view.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragment.getContext());
            view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            adapter = new TasksAdapter(fragment, fragment.getContext(), list);
            view.setAdapter(adapter);
            view.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(fragment.getContext()));
        } else {


            view.notifyItemInserted(list.size());
            view.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: @malli try this **`notifyItemInserted(list.size());`**

Comment: @malli try this **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`** after calling **`adapter.updateList(list);`** from fragment

Comment: I already tried with that you can see that code commented in the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157777/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-malli).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `Fragment` class like...

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: yes i tried with this also but no luck, you can see i commented that line in my code..

Answer (score 0):

have a same issue. In my case there was error message in the logcat *RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout*

which i have fixed with following code

```
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

then the notifyDataSetChanged start work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why sometimes we are not creating two instances of the adapter and also we are on the main thread adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working In this case just call the notifyDataSetChanged() method from the Adapter class.

```
adapter.setNewValue(newlist)
```

and on AdapterClass

```
fun setNewValue(newlist:ArrayList<Any>) {
list = newlist
notifyDataSetChanged()  
}
```